# Get Class Type of inherited object?

Tags: c#, types

In C#, how can I get the inherited Class Type of an object where the object is an inherited object instead of the Type of the instantiated object?

Here is some code:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public virtual void GetClassType()
    {
        var type = this.GetType();
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
    }
}
public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public override void GetClassType()
    {
        base.GetClassType();
        var type = this.GetType();
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
    }
}
public class ClassC : ClassB
{
    public override void GetClassType()
    {
        base.GetClassType();
        var type = this.GetType();
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
    }
}

private void GetClassType()
{
    var objectA = new ClassC();
    objectA.GetClassType();
}
```

The GetClassType method outputs the following to the console:

> ClassC 
>   ClassC
>   ClassC

Is it possible to get the Type of the Class, instead of the Type of the object such that the following is the console output?

> ClassA 
>   ClassB
>   ClassC

Comment: Please include a code example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the base type

Comment: Can't answer because it is closed, but instead of `this.GetType().Name` use `nameof(ClassA)`, `nameof(ClassB)` and `nameof(ClassC)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this

```
class A {}

class B : A {}
```

You can do this:

```
var b = new B();
var baseType = b.GetType().BaseType;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got the class which inherits the base type you already know which class it inherits.

if you want to check you can do as follows.

```
if(object is BaseType)
{
 //Dostuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

class MyClass
{
}

class MyClass2: MyClass
{
}
namespace Appl
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         System.Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyClass2).BaseType.Name);
      }
   }
}
```